# Can I create a simple gui directly on top of my game code?

Tags: python, user-interface

I am relatively new to coding and I'm currently doing my a level computer science coursework. I'm doing a text based RPG game in python 3. The problem I've ran into is I've coded the entire game with the outputs into the console of VS code, but I need to create a gui for the game. Just a simple window with one textbox that outputs everything the console outputs currently and a textbox that allows for any user input via typing. And maybe a backdrop for the gui. I've scoured the internet for solutions but I cannot find one. The gui don't need to be very fancy. Does anyone have the knowledge of any modules of ways I can easily slap a gui ontop of my code? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Tkinter, Qt are two libraries to make GUIs in Python

Answer (score 1):

For a basic GUI you can use TKinter: [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)
It's very easy to use and there are a lot example on the web that you can reference

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the [**tkinter**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) (“Tk interface”) package for this. It's a simple and straightforward standard interface in Python to the Tcl/Tk GUI toolkit, and the only GUI framework that comes built into Python itself. Considering your mentioned requirements for the project, you should easily be able to create what you want — an entry widget, for instance ([example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-entry-widget/)).